# Public Transportation Bike Rack Size

Tags: transportation

I have [TX36 E bike](http://www.etravelbikes.com/). Had no idea when purchased that the overall length is 6 feet (183 cm)  which is probably 6 inches (15 cm) longer than most bicycles. It does not fit into both front and rear tire slots. I have been using a heavy duty strap to secure front wheel.

It has no been brought to my attention I will no longer be able to put my bike on a rack. My problem is I am a disabled veteran and have no other way to get around. Looking for suggestions. I thought about a smaller wheel I could swap out for transit purposes only but axle widths are not the same. I thought about lengthening my control and brake cables that would let me spin handlebars and wheel 180 degrees. anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your link is dead.

Comment: Found the bike through Google and it's hard to say whether changing out the cables is practical.  I'd suggest you find a friendly neighborhood bike shop (or maybe a "bike coop" where volunteers work) to see if they can figure out something.

Comment: It's not actually that much longer than most bikes. My tourer is actually a little longer, but it's unusually large

Comment: @DanielRHicks Link fixed, just needed to drop the s from https.

Comment: Can you tell us which city and mode of transportation you're using?

Comment: Changing to smaller wheels is unlikely to help either (though a creative thought) - your pedals will be closer to the ground and you're more likely to strike the pedal on the road surface. You have disk brakes - if you had rim brakes then this would be impossible. Ultimately, reducing the wheel size will not help because it does nothing to shrink the wheelbase.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to spin the front wheel around may help but the stock image shows a light which will get in the way.   Also, I doubt you'll save 15 cm that way - the rake on most bikes is far less than that.

Changing to smaller wheels is unlikely to help either (though a creative thought) - your pedals will be closer to the ground and you're more likely to strike the pedal on the road surface.    You have disk brakes - if you had rim brakes then this would be impossible.   Ultimately, reducing the wheel size will **not help** because it does nothing to shrink the wheelbase.  That is - the axles are still in the same relative place.

Positive options

1. *Ride your bike* instead of taking the bus.  Perhaps you could buy a second battery to add to your range?
2. Consider the adage about "throwing good money..."  It could be time to sell this bike and buy one that matches all your needs - ie fits on a bus rack.

As a disabled person, are there any sources of assistance you can tap into to help fund this?  Not familiar with your country.

Good luck!

Comment: If you do change the bike, and assuming you get an e-bike again, those that mount the battery over the rear wheel tend to be shorter.  The frame on yours is stretched to make room for the battery pack

Answer (score -1):

I do not think shortening of your bike to fit into existing rack would be reasonable or even feasible. Extending your rack, or finding one that is adjustable or large enough would probably easier and cheaper solution.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to use a rack on public transport

Comment: It's not the asker's rack: it's the [rack on the front of a public bus](https://kingcounty.gov/depts/transportation/metro/travel-options/bike.aspx).

Comment: Good thinking, but not applicable in this case.